# How to match the first occurence of a repeating pattern on the same line?

Tags: regular-expression, search, substitute

I'd like to replace the following code:

```
ThisIsALoooongNameOfATwoDArray[100-rowIndex][j-2]-ThisIsALoooongNameOfATwoDArray[100+rowIndex][j+2];
```

by

```
Ptr[j-2]-Ptr[j+2];
```

I tried the command `:%s/This.*ex\]/Ptr/g` (and `/gc` variation), It turns out the regular expression performs the longest matching and the result becomes

```
Ptr[j+2];
```

Is there any simple way to achieve my goal? (I know I can delete it one by one and/or use `q` macro. Just wonder if we can do something using the "restricted" regular expression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
s/\mThis.\{-}]/Ptr/g
```

`\{-}` will match as few as possible characters before the following character in the regex. This allows to match only the first pair of brackets.

To be more detailled:

- `\m` use magic flavor of regex
- `This` match literally the string `This`
- `.\{-}]` match as few as possible character before the following `]`.

Answer (score 1):

A greedy alternative:

```
:%s/This[^]]*ex\]/Ptr/g
```

Where:

- `[^]]*` matches anything but `]`

  - `ex\]` matches literally `ex]`